# How to call a onclick event using Ferrum::Browser

Tags: ruby, selenium, web-scraping

I have a code using `Selenium::WebDriver` for scraping a web page.

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome)
driver.navigate.to(search_url)
driver.find_element(:name, 'searchText').send_keys('text')
driver.find_element(:name, 'searchButton').click
```

I tried to replace the code with `Ferrum::Brower`, but it didn't work.

```
browser = Ferrum::Browser.new
browser.goto(search_url)
browser.at_css('input[name=searchText]').focus.type('text')
browser.at_css('input[name=searchButton]').click
```

When the `searchButton` is clicked, the page doesn't move to a result page.

This is the input tag for search.

```
<input class="activeButton" onclick="submitPage(document.forms['form1'],document.forms['form1'].ListShow);" value="Search" type="button" name="searchButton">
```

How can I call `onclick` event using Ferrum?

Comment: Add selenium capybara watir tag to get the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to `type` method I need to focus the `Ferrum::Node` instance before clicking it.

```
- browser.at_css('input[name=searchButton]').click
+ browser.at_css('input[name=searchButton]').focus.click
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use #submit method directly on the form.

```
browser.at_css('form').submit
```